# How to create my own component library based on Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js, vue-cli-3

I want create my component library based on Vuetify and publish on npm.

Vuetify has already vue-plugin standard installation and use vuetify-loader, I think was a more complex scenario than plain HTML component.

For example, I want create my **Login Form**, my **Article Page**, my default **calendar picker** with preset values.

There's a standard way or guide to do this or a sample to do that?

I use last version of vuetify (2.0.7)

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html

Comment: vuetify is just a framework, you need to include it in main js and you can use vue component template to create your own.

Comment: @menteora Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm stuck at the project setup for the consuming package.

Comment: Yes, @Johannes. All my problem was related to `npm pack`. See my repository: https://github.com/menteora/vuetify-extra I currenty use it

Comment: @menteora I am about to start on a similar project, and started thinking if I would run into issues since the components I am building will be using vuetify, which means they will need to include a `v-app` component for everything to work properly. If this library is then imported into another project that is using vuetify, won't that cause an issue since there will be 2 `v-app` components? Or if you develop a component library using vuetify can it only be imported into another project based on vuetify, which would mean you don't need to include `v-app` in the component library.

Comment: @flyingL123 have you found an answer to your question?

Comment: @belov91 kind of. It's been a while since I asked this question so hard to recall. If there is something specific you need help with let me know and I can try to assist.

Answer (score 3):

I just got it working for Vue3/Vuetify3. In a nutshell (using pnpm, vite, typescript, Vue plugin):

Create the component as a new project:

```
pnpm create vue@latest
-> your-plugin
-> Typescript
-> ESLint
cd <project>
echo auto-install-peers = true > .npmrc
pnpm add -D vuetify rollup-plugin-typescript2
```

Then remove all the components and make your own component instead.
Create src\components\index.ts and src\YourPlugin.ts

**src\components\index.ts**

```
export {default as YourComponent} from "./YourComponent.vue"
```

**src\YourPlugin.ts**

```
import type { App } from "vue"
import { YourComponent } from "./components"
export default {
    install: (app: App) => {
        app.component("YourComponent", YourComponent)
    }
};
```

**vite.config.ts**

Add to the `imports`:

```
import vuetify from 'vite-plugin-vuetify'
import typeScript2 from "rollup-plugin-typescript2"
```

Add to the `plugins`:

```
vuetify({
  autoImport: true,
}),
typeScript2({
  check: false,
  include: ["src/components/*.vue"],
  tsconfigOverride: {
    compilerOptions: {
      sourceMap: true,
      declaration: true,
      declarationMap: true,
    }
  },
  exclude: [
    "vite.config.ts"
  ]
})
```

Add a new section `build` to the defineConfig:

```
  build: {
    cssCodeSplit: false,
    lib: {
      entry: "./src/YourPlugin.ts",
      formats: ["es", "cjs"],
      name: "CommonVtfyPlugin",
      fileName: format => (format == "es" ? "index.js" : "index.cjs"),
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ["vue", "vuetify/lib"],
      output: {
        globals: {
          vue: "Vue",
          vuetify: "Vuetify",
            'vuetify/components': 'VuetifyComponents',
            'vuetify/directives': 'VuetifyDirectives'
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

**dist\index.d.ts**

I have not figured out how to generate this on yet. But this is a generic stand in:

```
declare const _default: any;
export default _default;
```

**package.json**

Add this:

```json
  "type": "module",
  "exports": {
    ".": "./dist/index.js"
  },
  "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
```

You can use it in any Vue project by importing it as a plugin:

```
import YourComponent from 'your-plugin'
app.use(YourComponent)
```

No guarantees on how optimized that is (feedback welcome).. but it works (tm)..
A more detailed answer can be found [pnpm monorepo: how to set up a simple reusable (vue) component for reuse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75117561/pnpm-monorepo-how-to-set-up-a-simple-reusable-vue-component-for-reuse) (any updates will primarily be updated in that answer as well, if any)